# Java Apache POI and JDBC: Smart way to fetch huge amount of data into Excel

Tags: java, apache, jdbc, apache-poi

I want to fetch a huge amount of data (over 100.000 rows with 50 columns) from my Oracle database into an Excel File using Java Apache POI and Oracle JDBC. That is working well for small amount of data but what is the smartest way to handle tasks like this? Maybe using multithreading? I get errors like "java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space" although I already increased the memory to 1024MB.

This is my current code:

```
public void fetchDataIntoExcelFile(String sqlStmt){

    // Check whether jdbc driver exists or not
    try {
        Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("Please install the Oracle JDBC Driver!");
        e.printStackTrace();
        return;
    }

    // Try to establish a connection to the db
    try {
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@myserver", "user", "password");
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return;
    }

    XSSFWorkbook wbx = new XSSFWorkbook();
    XSSFSheet sheet = wbx.createSheet();
    FileOutputStream fos = null;

    try {
        fos = new FileOutputStream("filename.xlsx");
        wbx.write(fos);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("Error occured while creating file.");
    }

    // Execute SQL Statement if connection was successful
    if (conn != null) {
        try {

            Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sqlStmt);
            ResultSetMetaData columns   = rs.getMetaData();
            XSSFRow row                 = null;
            XSSFCell cell               = null;

            // Start writing results into the excel file
            int i = 0;
            while (rs.next()){
                row = sheet.createRow(i++);


                for (int j = 1; j <= columns.getColumnCount(); j++){


                    cell = row.createCell(j);

                    if (i == 1){
                        cell.setCellValue(columns.getColumnLabel(j));
                    }else{
                        cell.setCellValue(rs.getString(columns.getColumnLabel(j)));
                    }
                }
            }

            try {
                wbx.write(fos);
                fos.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println("Connection Failed!");
            e.printStackTrace();
            return;

        } 
    } else {
        System.out.println("Failed to make connection!");
    }

}
```

Comment: apache poi has multiple APIs(use models)-  try https://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/how-to.html#sxssf

Comment: Can you use jasper template( created by iReport or jasper studio) and then export it to Excel file using poi?
if you want to do that, then i can help you out here.

Answer (score 0):

It helped to use the SXSSF API as suggested. Here is the link:
https://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/how-to.html#sxssf